# Mustache (Nustache) arbitrarily rendering some of list inline

Tags: c#, .net, email, mustache

I'm using the code:

```
{{#Object}} 
{{{Name}}} - {{{Property}}}
{{/Object}}
```

to render a list, but halfway through the list, it'll start printing the list on the same line, which it will continue doing until the end of the list. We use this within emails, and our preview pane renders it within a `<pre>` tag, and it looks fine. When it's set as the body of an email, we get the line breaking problem. It'll render like the following:

```
Object1Name - Object1Property
Object2Name - Object2Property 
Object3Name - Object3Property
Object4Name - Object4Property Object5Name - Object5Property Object6Name - Object6Property
```

There are also instances where it puts the entire list on the same line, and there are instances where it doesn't happen, most of the time it starts about halfway through the list and continues.
any help or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that the first three object property values here end in "\n"? Maybe they're *all* being rendered on the same line, but those don't look like it because they end with a newline character.

Comment: Turns out that it's a problem in outlook when rendering plaintext emails.